# Is there a way to create offline transaction with cleos (or any other safe tool)?

Tags: cleos, transfer

Trying to transfer EOS on main net using air gapped computer. Want to print  a transaction and then type it manually.

Answer (score 1):

I write it myself with java, cleos only support to sign from keosd, if you'd like, try to reuse the wallet-sign method.